# wordpress form button color change does not work

Tags: wordpress, button, colors, search-form

This is simpelest thing ever but it does not work. I have a searchform with a button. Ans i want to make the button blue. Easy right?

This is the search form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit2" value="Search" />
</form>
```

and a little bit of CSS.

```
.search-submit2 {
    /*text-align: center;*/
    background: url(images/search2.png);
    /*background-size: 50px 50px;*/
   /*  width: 50px; width of image */
   /*  height: 50px; /* height of image */
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

I see the background image (is transparent png) displaying inside the butt i getthe same result.

Anyone see anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

use `background: #fff url()` instead. Debug to check if the image address is right.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Add **.search-submit2** class in CSS File

```
.search-submit2 {
  color: #000;
  background: #000AFF !important;
 }
```